# How to create private screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I use react native and react-navigation. Now i have:

```
const MainNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Users: {screen: Users},
    Login: {screen: Login}
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Users',
});

const Navigator = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);


export default function App() {
  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Navigator/>
      </Provider>
  );
}
```

But how do I add private screen only for logged-in users? If this the user is a guest then I dont want to show the private screen in the nav bar, otherwise, if the user is logged in then show it.

Comment: What is a private screen ?

Comment: Private screen is a module of app. Like another component Images. This screen see only logged-in users

Comment: To separate navigation between guest users and logged-in users, switch navigator is the best choice, this is and an article that show you the flow of it.  https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the user is logged in, and then add private screens dynamically.

```
const navigationScreens = {
    Users: {screen: Users},
    Login: {screen: Login}
}

if(isUserLoggedIn) {
   navigationScreens["PrivateScreen1"] = {
      screen: MyPrivateScreen1
   } 
   navigationScreens["PrivateScreen2"] = {
      screen: MyPrivateScreen2
   } 
}

const MainNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(navigationScreens,{
    initialRouteName: 'Users',
});

...
```